# Unable to find my Whatsapp/App data on my device?

Tags: android

I tried serching Android/data/ but my package is not listed.
i installed one of my whatsapp through Clone app (v1.1.4) want to backup my whatsapp data from my device, but cannot find where my second whatsapp is being stored by clone app.

Comment: Please explain your issue with proper details. Add some images or logs.

Answer (score 0):

I once also did this with WhatsApp some years ago. I found the cloned one in `/storage/emulated/999/WhatsApp`.
The normal WhatsApp App would be in `/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp`. Found this via a FileManager. I used [Explorez](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.palmtronix.explorez.v1&hl=en&gl=US) for it

Comment: I tried using Explorez, try to  use this URL storage/emulated/999/WhatsApp , it says Error director not found.

Comment: Maybe this changed from the versions of clone. I used and older clone version